# Angular and Ionic - why this directive does not register on change on ion-input?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular2-directives, ionic3

I'm trying make [this directive](https://github.com/NepipenkoIgor/ng2-mask) work with ion input, however I'm having two issues I have no idea how to solve:

1 - Can't load the mask when the ion-input is shown - The problem is that the input element only appears at the nativeElement's childNodes after some time, so I didn't found a hook to implement. To try solve it I put some code inside a setTimeout, this way I can find the wrapped input:

```
public ngOnInit():void {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this._element=this.findElement();
        resolvedPromise.then(() => this._applyValueChanges());
    },1000);
}
findElement():any{
    if (this._elementRef.nativeElement.tagName === 'INPUT') {
        return this._elementRef.nativeElement
    } else {
        let index;
        for(index=0;index<this._elementRef.nativeElement.childNodes.length;index++)
            if (this._elementRef.nativeElement.childNodes[index].tagName === 'INPUT')
                return this._elementRef.nativeElement.childNodes[index];
    }
}
```

2 - The other problem is that registerOnChange method is never called, this way I can't update the model to remove the special chars:

```
public registerOnChange(fn:any):void {
    this._onChange = fn;
    return;
}
```

So, I would like to know: how can I make registerOnChange work with ion-input element? Is there a way I can find the wrapped input in onInit without using a setTimeout?

Answer (score 1):

1. Answer for first question is that you can use  ionViewDidLoad() {} this function in place of your function.
2. On blur event is not part of latest ionic it has been removed so you can use this in place of that

   it will work.

It all worked for me hope it work for you as well.

Comment: <ion-input type="" (focusout)="updateEndDate($event)"></ion-input> use this